# Is it possible to Import/Export VLC key bindings?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, hotkeys, export

I'd like to be able to import and export my "Hotkeys" preferences between different VLC installations.

Specifically, I'm looking to use KMPlayer keybindings with VLC, and I'd like to not have to do it multiple times for multiple machines.

Answer (score 8):

You can try using the same config file (where all preferences such as hotkeys are stored) on all your PCs. As per the [FAQ](https://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html#Config):

> **Where does VLC store its config file?**
>
> Currently, a config file is created on a per user basis (there is no
>   global configuration file). If you modify the available options in VLC
>   and save the new configuration, then a configuration file will be
>   created in your user directory. The precise location of this file
>   depends on the Operating System you are running:
>
> - Linux / Unix: $(HOME)/.config/vlc/vlcrc (v0.9.0 and above), $(HOME)/.vlc/vlcrc (v0.8 and older)
> - Mac OS X: HOME/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc HOME/Library/Preferences/VLC (v0.9 and older)
> - Windows 95/98/ME: C:\Windows\Application Data\vlc\vlcrc
> - Windows 2000/XP: C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\vlc\vlcrc
> - Windows Vista/7: C:\Users\%username%\Application Data\vlc\vlcrc
>     (or C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\vlc\vlcrc)
> - BeOS: config/settings/vlcrc

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes during vlc update these hotkeys config gets misplaced i.e some key does something else.